# Passing value from PHP script to Python script

Tags: php, python, variables, exec

I looked at the other questions similar to this one, but can't figure this out still.

I have a basic php file that does this:

```
?php
$item='example';
$tmp = exec("python testscriptphp.py .$item");
echo $tmp;
?
```

While succesfully calls python that I have running on my webhostserver.  Now in my python script i want something like this:

```
item=$item
print item
```

Basically I'm asking how to pass variables from PHP to a python script and then back to php if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) (Python) and [$argv](http://php.net/argv]) (PHP) ? :)

Answer (score 31):

Although netcoder pretty much gave you the answer in his comment, here's an example:

Python->PHP

example.py

```
import os
os.system("/usr/bin/php example2.php whatastorymark")
```

example2.php

```
<?php
    echo $argv[1];

?>
```

PHP->Python

```
<?php
    $item='example';
    $tmp = exec("python testscriptphp.py .$item");
    echo $tmp;

?>
```

testscriptphp.py

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Here's how PHP's command line argument passing works: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php
The same for Python: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: is it possible to update the variable rather than echo? from python to php?

Comment: @ravi I think, `$argv[1] = 1234;`

Answer (score 4):

write a php file example index.php:

```
<?PHP
$sym = $_POST['symbols'];
echo shell_exec("python test.py .$sym");
?>
```

$sym is a parameter we passining to test.py python file.
then create a python example test.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score -1):

**In php file**

```
 $a = "..\Python\Python39\python.exe  ../frontend/upload/main.py '$param1''$param2'";

 $output = shell_exec($a);

 echo $output;

 ..\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

python path in my system, you can change with your path

```
 ../frontend/upload/main.py
```

it's my python script path

**In python file**

```
import sys

param_1_ = sys.argv[1]
param_2=  sys.argv[2]
```