# How to pass PHP variable values to Python via shell_exec

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have some variables defined in a PHP file. I then call a python script from the PHP with these variables as arguments. *HOWEVER* the values of the variables do not carry over to my python script, it seems as though they as passed as strings and not as variables:

```
$first = "doggy";
$second = "kitty";

$command = escapeshellcmd('python ./script.py $first $second');
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

The above code produces not "doggy" and "kitty" respectively in my Python script, but literally "$first" and "$second". I want doggy and kitty.

For example when I print in Python:

```
print sys.argv[1];
>>$first
```

is the output I am receiving.

My Python script is NOT outputting anything, the script interacts with an API that I wish to use these variables with.

I have tried these previous posts which seem to be near what I am asking. I am either not understanding them, or they are not working. Some answers are too technical or too vague.

[Passing value from PHP script to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977125/passing-value-from-php-script-to-python-script)

[PHP <-> Python variable exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062291/php-python-variable-exchange?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If shell_exec is not the best way for this, I am open to new ideas. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to look at my post.

Comment: try replacing single quotes with double quotes: `$command = escapeshellcmd("python ./script.py $first $second");`

Comment: Use double quotes, not single

Comment: @Yamakenji, cdarke. Thank you. It has literally been HOURS...

Answer (score 3):

A single quoted string will be displayed literally, while a double quoted string will interpret things like variables and new line sequences (\n).

Therefore, change from single to double quotes:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python ./script.py $first $second");
```

Read more about strings in the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks Emil, it worked. I am both amazingly frustrated and relieved at the same time.