# Run python script inside php and pass file as a parameter

Tags: python, php, yii

I am trying to run a python script inside php file, the problem is i can't pass the file as an argument

something like this

$a ="python /umana/frontend/upload/main.py 'filename' ";

$output =shell_exec($a);

The real problem is, the file is not opening in python script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing value from PHP script to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977125/passing-value-from-php-script-to-python-script)

Comment: i want to pass a hex file as a parameter,i can pass the parameter but  if i try to open in python its not working

Comment: append your python code, the problem might be there, is the filename absolute path or relative? If relative, it could be incorrect in main.py location

Comment: also maybe more of your php code could help, check out how to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved

$a ="python-path  C:/python program path '$file_uploaded_path_as_param' ";

$output =shell_exec($a);

we want to add the python path before python script.